# Which macro to wrap Mac OS X specific code in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, macros

While reading various C and C++ sources, I have encountered two macros `__APPLE__` and `__OSX__`. I found plenty of use of `__OSX__` in various codes, especially those originating from `*BSD` systems.

However, sometimes I find that testing `__OSX__` only is not sufficient and I have to complete tests with `__APPLE__` macro.

The [Porting Command Line Unix Tools to Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2071.html#Section10) guides specifies `__APPLE__` and additionally `__APPLE_CC__` but does **not** mention `__OSX__`.

The [Porting from GCC](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/GCC40PortingReleaseNotes/Articles/PortingToGCC.html) guide says:

> - Use `#ifdef __GNUC__` to wrap any GCC-specific code.
> - Use `#ifdef __APPLE_CC__` to wrap any Mac OS X-specific code.

Again, no mention about `__OSX__` macro.

What macro is predefined on Mac OS X platform and XCode development environment that should be used to distinguish OSX-specific code in C/C++ programs?

Where is the `__OSX__` macro defined? Is it `*BSD` specific macro?

Comment: Qt uses even a different define: `Q_OS_OSX`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It all depends.

Each macro specifies something different in meaning.
See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002850-SW13

> `__APPLE__`
>
> This macro is defined in any Apple computer.
>
> `__APPLE_CC__`
>
> This macro is set to an integer that represents the version number of
>       the compiler. This lets you distinguish, for example, between compilers
>       based on the same version of GCC, but with different bug fixes or features.
>       Larger values denote later compilers.
>
> `__OSX__`
>
> Presumably the OS is a particular variant of OS X

So given the above definitions I would use `__APPLE__` to distinguish apple specific code.

Comment: Yes, I understand the difference of `__APPLE__` and `__APPLE_CC__` macros - I linked from my questions to the very same guide. BTW, you included `__OSX__` macro within the guide citation and one may understand it is explanation from the linked guide, but it is your comment. I got a bit confused :-)

Comment: @prewett: Your point? That is why there is a link to apple documentation. I recommend using `__APPLE__` in the above answer.

Comment: @LokiAstari:  The question asked for determining MacOS X specifically, but `__APPLE__` is also defined for iOS.  `__OSX__` seems like what you'd want, so I used it and it didn't work, because it does not exist and I'd like to save people the effort.  In fact, this answer (use `__APPLE__`) is wrong if you want to distinguish between OS X and iOS.

Comment: @prewett Then you should ask (and answer) your own question rather than add nonsensical comments to a completely different question. Note: this question has nothing to do with iOS (Which you can tell because it was asked and answered before iOS existed), nor did your comment have anything to do with iOS and the apple documentation was never specific on the meaning of `__OSX__` (as shown above).

Comment: Use `#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)` – see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/51539096/471478

Answer (score 16):

Here is a [nice list](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/) of macros for operating systems.

There's little info on `__OSX__` on the web. You'll be safe with `__APPLE__`.

Comment: +1 to you and Martin York. Thanks! However, I am still very curious about where `__OSX__` comes from, so I'll wait a bit with marking my question as answered.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
```

to distinguish Apple operating systems.

You can further use `TARGET_OS_MAC` and `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` to distinguish between macOS and iOS.

Full example:

```
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    /* Apple OSX and iOS (Darwin). */
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR == 1
    /* iOS in Xcode simulator */

#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE == 1
    /* iOS */

#elif TARGET_OS_MAC == 1
    /* macOS */

#endif
#endif
```

Regarding the question of *"where does `__OSX__` come from?"*:

> Some on-line lists of compiler macros (like this one) list `__MACOSX__`. Some forum comments (like these) claim `__OSX__` exists. These are incorrect. There are no such macros predefined by OSX compilers, but they may be defined by specific project Makefiles and platform-detector scripts like GNU autoconf.

Source: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system

Update – the above link is broken, see version in web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20180331065236/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system#OSXiOSandDarwin

Comment: This should be selected as the accepted answer. This is also how the Swift compiler checks if the OS is mac.

Comment: You can just edit the top answer to put the extra information in that one to make it better. It will be hard to raise this answer higher on a 12 year old question.

Answer (score 9):

I normally use `__MACH__` for this. It's been defined since the earliest version of OS X (and even before, presumably).

If you want to exclude the possibility that you might be compiling for some other OS that uses the Mach kernel then you can use [@scravy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51539096/253056) of:

```
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
```

Note also that if you're compiling generic C/C++ code, i.e. no Apple-speacific headers, so you are just interested in pre-defined compiler macros, you can check these as follows:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | egrep -i 'os_|mac|apple'
#define __APPLE_CC__ 6000
#define __APPLE__ 1
#define __ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__ 120000
#define __ENVIRONMENT_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__ 120000
#define __MACH__ 1
#define __VERSION__ "Apple LLVM 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)"
#define __apple_build_version__ 13160021
```

Comment: `__MACH__` is used for GNU/Hurd too because the latter currently uses a Mach kernel.

Comment: @KennyTM - thanks for that - I didn't know here were any other systems out there that use `__MACH__`. For my purposes it's good enough, though, as I typically only care about Mac OS X v Linux v Windows.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the tip, it's useful but it doesn't really answer my original question. I'd like to precisely know where the `__OSX__` comes from.

Comment: OK - sorry - I thought you just wanted suggestions as to what macro to use for OS X-specific code.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for such macro, but macro which is uniquely specified on Mac OS X and XCode. AFAIU, `__MACH__` is not unique for OSX. Thanks anyway.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_(kernel)#Software_based_on_Mach

Comment: So this wouldn't catch if someone was running GNU/Hurd on an Apple machine.

Answer (score 5):

See http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system#OSXiOSandDarwin

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#if TARGET_OS_MAC
   ...
#endif /* TARGET_OS_MAC */
#endif /* __APPLE__ */
```

Note that `__OSX__` does ***NOT*** exist, at least as of Xcode 9.

Also note that it is `#if TARGET_OS_MAC` not `#ifdef`.  It is always defined, but is 0 when not macOS.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming across this question >= 2019, I found there's a header "Availability.h".

In that header, are #defines like:

```
#define __MAC_10_0            1000
#define __MAC_10_1            1010
#define __MAC_10_2            1020
#define __MAC_10_3            1030
#define __MAC_10_4            1040
#define __MAC_10_5            1050
#define __MAC_10_6            1060
#define __MAC_10_7            1070
#define __MAC_10_8            1080
#define __MAC_10_9            1090
#define __MAC_10_10         101000
#define __MAC_10_10_2       101002
#define __MAC_10_10_3       101003
#define __MAC_10_11         101100
#define __MAC_10_11_2       101102
```

So you CAN tell if you're compiling on a particular MacOS platform.